# PHP - Predefine an array at the begining of a class for all methods to use

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a method within a class that returns a single array. This method is called within other methods inside the same class. Rather than keep defining `$data` at the begining of each method, is there a way og defining it at the begining of the extended class? Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve [simplified]

```
class Myclass extends AnotherClass
{
    protected $data = $this->getData(); // this does not wwork

    public function aMethod()
    {
        $data = $this->getData();

        $data['userName'];

        // code here that uses $data array()
    }

    public function aMethod1()
    {
        $data = $this->getData();

        // code here that uses $data array()
    }

    public function aMethod2()
    {
        $data = $this->getData();

        // code here that uses $data array()
    }

    public function aMethod2()
    {
        $data = $_POST;

        // code here that processes the $data
    }

    // more methods
}
```

Comment: You can set it in the __construct() function, then it'll be available to use for all the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put that assignment in the class constructor:

```
class MyClass extends AnotherClass {
    protected $variable;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->variable = $this->getData();
    }

}
```

**** UPDATE ****

You can also try the following

```
class MyClass extends AnotherClass {
    protected $variable;

    function __construct($arg1)
    {
        parent::__construct($arg1);
        $this->variable = parent::getData();
    }

}
```

According to your Parent class you need to pass the needed arguments

Comment: This causes a fata error because it breaks other methods within my class.

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe I miss something, but normally you would instantiate such variable in a constructor :

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->data = $this->getData();
}
```

Comment: This will not work as you are overriding the parent class constructor and `getData()` method is undefined.

Comment: Correct @Zeusarm, I tried this and had a suede of errors as I was overrdindg the parent contract as you so rightly point out

Answer (score 0):

```
class Myclass extends AnotherClass{

   protected $array_var;

   public __construct(){
      $this->array_var = $this->getData();
   }

   public function your_method_here(){
      echo $this->array_var;
   }
}
```

Comment: A few explaining sentences would be helpful. :-)

Comment: I think is clear...when you create the class "Myclass" automatically (with your constructor you have a variable "array_var" populated with the function "getData"